# database modeling mac app for ruby on rails development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, database-design

I am building web applications using Ruby on Rails and I would like to know what's the best tool for OS X to mock a new application from a functionality perspective and not graphic design. I would like to be able to get an idea of what the application will require in terms of resources before starting to write the code.

Thanks,
Cezar

Comment: So what are you looking for again? A database modeling tool as the title of your question suggests or a functionality mockup tool like the question suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQLEditor](http://www.malcolmhardie.com/sqleditor/) is pretty minimalistic, easy to use and supports exporting to Rails migrations.

Answer (score 1):

For any resource / application planning, I'd really just use a pen and paper :)

Is there any specific requirement as to the sort of functionality you are after?

Comment: yeah, pen and paper doesn't scale nicely and I'd like to have it on my laptop and be able to update it with ease.

Answer (score 1):

[Balsamiq](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)? It's flash based.

The trial has a nag, but other than that appears to be fully functional.

Answer (score 0):

I typically use OmniGraffle for this sort of thing.  You can download additional templates that allow you to do UML and database specific design.